# iOS8 simulators error

Tags: simulator, ios8, xcode6

Try to start my project on one iOS8 simulator and Xcode shows error:

An error was encountered while running (Domain = NSMachErrorDomain, Code = 5)
[image]

No one of iOS8 simulator can't be started. What to do?

Comment: Have you copied xcode from somewhere else? or have you downloaded a dmg and installed it?

Comment: Download dmg from developer center

Comment: @Maria did a download from dev center help?

Comment: This problem was with Xcode6 beta2 from dev center.
It was fixed in DP3

Comment: I'm having the same problem using DP3.

Comment: I'm having the same problem using DP5 (Version 6.0 (6A267n))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"iOS Simulator" -> "Reset Content And Settings..."
^ this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm still getting it.

Comment: This and a "Clean Build Folder" fixed it for me on Xcode 6 Beta 4.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same error just this morning, and I haven't completely figured it out, but I have observed something which might help you (or both of us, if anyone else stumbles across this and has more information). I was building a project which contained:

- the app itself
- a Today extension (widget)
- a Framework to share code between the app and the widget

The widget comes with TodayViewController.h/m, and I wanted to share this view controller with the app. So I changed the target membership of TodayViewController.m to my framework rather than the widget. (Did this in the Target Membership in the right sidebar.) I also set the TodayViewController.h to be part of the framework as a public header. When I did this, and then did a clean, I got this error when trying to run the app in the simulator, and also an "unknown error (null)" when trying to run on device. If I set TodayViewController.m's target membership to both the framework and the widget, I'm able to run the app in the simulator just fine.

Now, I don't know why this would be the case. I've declared my widget to depend on the framework, so it seems like it should work without my setting the target membership of TodayViewController.m to both widget and framework. If anyone else knows why this is the case, I'm all ears. But this is what I've found so far.

Comment: I've written about my own issues [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559392/ios-8-beta-today-extension-doesnt-recognize-embedded-framework) for reference.

Comment: Really strange behaviour, but I think it's just a bug.

Comment: I have the same scenario (app, today extension and framework) and exactly the same issue. I followed the session video about frameworks on the WWDC2014 and they didn't include the .m to the "widget" target. This solves the issue, but use this just as a temporary solution

Comment: I was able to find the actual problem. Probably you were doing the same thing as me, have all the code on the framework and no controllers on the widget. The problem is that if you don't have at least one compiled file on the widget's target, xcode is not going to create a binary for the widget and it will return this error. That's why it worked by including the .m file on the widget target

Comment: I did also have no controllers in the widget and noticed that was probably the problem. Is it documented anywhere that Xcode will refuse to create a binary for the widget if it has no controllers?

Comment: It's not that you need at least a controller, what you need is a compiled binary for the widget. Without compiled code (could be an empty NSObject..) xcode is not going to create a binary.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem tonight too. I was not able to get my app to run if my resource directory was a "folder reference" (aka blue folder). Once I re-added my resource directory as a "folder group" (normal folder) instead my app ran fine. Not sure if this is the case for you, but it solved my problem. GL.

Comment: For me it didn't work. If I add a folder reference the xcode project keeps crashing, and even if I checkout a previous version using git (!) or delete the current project and start a new project on the same folder with the same name (!) the project doesn't start. I had to start a new project somewhere else, copying all my files and being careful to do not add a folder reference.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today using DP3.

When I tried to delete the Derived Data folder from Organizer, it showed me some kind of permission error. I then manually deleted the folder from Finder, rebuilt, and voila! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you ever get and error like this, where xcode doesn't say much, just a error code, try first to check the actual problem on the system console.

**Applications -> Utilities -> Console**

On my case I was able to see that xcode was trying to copy the widget's binary and it was not able to find it. I was able to find out that without at least one compiled file on the extension's target, xcode is not going to create the binary for the extension.